# Redux not passing state to container

Tags: reactjs, redux, containers, state

I'm having a problem receiving the state on my ActiveMessage object from my reducers.  When I click an object on the message list, I can see that it flows through the action, through the correct reducer, but doesn't arrive on the local props for ActiveMessage.  I'm not sure why it's not receiving the state on active_message prop.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this isnt working?

message_list.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import MessageStub from "./message_stub";
import {activateMessage} from "../../actions/index";
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class MessageList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selected_message: null
        };

        this.selectMessage = this.selectMessage.bind(this);
    }

    selectMessage(event, index, message){
        this.setState({selected_message: index});
        this.props.activateMessage(message);

    }

    renderMessageList() {
        return this.props.message_list.map((message, index) =>
            <tr key={index}>
                <td className={index === this.state.selected_message ? "message-stub-body active-message-stub" : "message-stub-body"}
                    onClick={(e) => this.selectMessage(e, index, message)}>
                    <MessageStub />
                </td>
                <td>
                    {index === this.state.selected_message && <div className="message-stub-arrow"/>}
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="message-list">
                <table className="message-list-table">
                    <tbody>
                    {this.renderMessageList()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        message_list: state.message_list,
    };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({activateMessage: activateMessage}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MessageList);
```

active_message.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import MessageOut from "./message_out";
import MessageIn from "./message_in";

class ActiveMessage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.scrollToBottom = this.scrollToBottom.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }

    scrollToBottom() {
        this.el.scrollTop = this.el.scrollHeight;
    }

    renderMessages(){
        return this.props.active_message.messages.map((message, i) =>
            <MessageOut key={i} onClick={() => {
                this.scrollToBottom
            }}/>
        );

    }
    render() {
        console.log("rendering");
        console.log(this.props.active_message);
        if(!this.props.active_message){
            return <div>loading...</div>
        }
        return (
            <div className="active-message-div">
                <div className="active-message"
                     ref={el => {
                         this.el = el;
                     }}>
                    {this.renderMessages()}
                </div>
                <div className="message-reply-div">
                    <textarea className="message-reply-input" placeholder="Type a message..."/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log("mapping");
    return{
        active_message: state.active_message
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ActiveMessage);
```

actions/index.js

```
export const ACTIVATE_MESSAGE = 'activate_message';

export function activateMessage(message){
    console.log("calling action " + message)
    return{
        type: ACTIVATE_MESSAGE,
        payload: message
    };
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import MessageListReducer from './reducer_message_list';
import ActiveMessageReducer from './reducer_active_message';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    message_list: MessageListReducer,
    active_message: ActiveMessageReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducer_active_message.js

```
import {ACTIVATE_MESSAGE} from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = null, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ACTIVATE_MESSAGE:
            console.log("reducing through ACTIVE_MESSAGE");
            return action.payload;
    }
    return state;
}
```

reducer_message_list.js

```
export default function(){
    return[
        {
            user: {
                first_name: "First",
                last_name: "Last",
                type: "P"
            },
            messages: [
                {
                    message: "hi",
                    inbound: true
                },
                {
                    message: "bye",
                    inbound: false
                }
            ]


        },
        {
            user: {
                first_name: "First2",
                last_name: "Last2",
                type: "O"
            },
            messages: [
                {
                    message: "hi",
                    inbound: true
                },
                {
                    message: "bye",
                    inbound: false
                }
            ]


        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you see your active_message in your store with redux dev tools ?

Comment: I'm new to React, and I don't know of any dev tools.  I've just installed redux devtools from the chrome store, but it seems to not work at all for me.

Comment: it looks like you are not changing any status in your reducer, you just return the payload. You should use the `switch` in your reducer to return a new redux state when an action is fired, something similar to `return state.set("active_message", action.payload);`

Comment: @Dario

returning the action.payload should be fine since it will be return to the root of the reducer which name is active_message. No ?

Comment: @user1637466

 Redux dev tool is essential ! It gives you a visual interface for your store.


You need to add the following line to your Provider store.


<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())}>
    <YourApp/>
  </Provider>

Comment: I think I have narrowed it down to the component not re-rendering.  I used Redux Devtools to see that it is in fact updating the state.  Any clue why it's not rerendering?

Answer (score 0):

I have loaded this into CodeSandbox. I'm able to get this to work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/7y9nlvvprq

NOTE: Your reducer_message_list is not a reducer, just a static data set.

Comment: Did you change anything that would affect the state?

Comment: I did not have your <MessageOut/> component, so a faked it. I also outputting the user details within <ActiveMessage/> to show that state was being passed in.

Comment: I did not change state